# How to use html sensor api in Vue

Tags: api, vue.js, sensors

I try to use html senor api like "accelerometer" in my mobile web,
In pure html env it has work, but in Vue it failed.

I use this sample code can run on pure html
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Sensor_APIs

And enable chrome flag senor:
chrome:/flags/#enable-generic-sensor-extra-classes

In html I use this

```
let accelerometer = null;
try {
    accelerometer = new Accelerometer({ referenceFrame: 'device' });
    accelerometer.addEventListener('error', event => {
        // Handle runtime errors.
        if (event.error.name === 'NotAllowedError') {
            // Branch to code for requesting permission.
        } else if (event.error.name === 'NotReadableError' ) {
            console.log('Cannot connect to the sensor.');
        }
    });
    accelerometer.addEventListener('reading', () => reloadOnShake(accelerometer));
    accelerometer.start();
} catch (error) {
    // Handle construction errors.
    if (error.name === 'SecurityError') {
        // See the note above about feature policy.
        console.log('Sensor construction was blocked by a feature policy.');
    } else if (error.name === 'ReferenceError') {
        console.log('Sensor is not supported by the User Agent.');
    } else {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

But in Vue I have error like this

```
Sensor is not supported by the User Agent.
```

And when just declare :let accelerometer = new Accelerometer(), would get error meaasge like this

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Accelerometer is not defined
    at eval
```

How can I get accelerometer value in Vue env.

Comment: Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The browser you're using to run your Vue app has not had the `enable-generic-sensor-extra-classes` flag set

Comment: @Phil Can Vue app enable-generic-sensor-extra-classes? I use same veriosn chrome browser